# awk variable in the condition part?

Tags: awk

I needed to filter a file when the numbers in the first column are the same as those in the fifth and the sixth and I wrote

```
awk -F, 'gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "G", $1) == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $5) &&
         gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "G", $1) == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $6)'
```

which worked well enough for me and the file is small enough to not be a problem but I am still wondering: is it possible to assign `gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "G", $1)` to a variable so I do not need to do the replacement twice?

Edit:

`123.4.5,B,C,D,12-345,1-2-34/5`

that's a line we want to keep. Because the 1st,5th and 6th columns after throwing away the non-numeric characters are 12345.

`123,B,C,D,12-345,1-2-34/5`

This is a line we want to filter out.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise testable sample input and expected output otherwise you're likely to get an answer to your question instead of a solution to your problem.

Comment: Is there a reason that `awk -F, '$1==$5 && $1==$6' file` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any single expression is valid in the *pattern* statement
(ref. [Standard Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16)).

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk '(var=gsub(/e/,""))&&var==2'
thr
```

Comment: Note: `(var=gsub(/e/,""))` the `()` are very important, it will break otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

another alternative is

```
 awk '{a[1]=$1; a[5]=$5; a[6]=$6; 
       for(k in a) sub(/[^0-9]/,"",a[k])} 
      a[1]==a[5] && a[1]==a[6]' file
```

or even

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[1]; a[5]; a[6]} 
          {for(k in a) 
             {a[k]=$k; sub(/[^0-9]/,"",a[k])}} 
     a[1]==a[5] && a[1]==a[6]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  -

```
awk -F, '{kk=gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "G", $1); if(kk == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $5) && kk == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $6)) print $0}'
```

Comment: Yes, that's one way to solve the overall problem but not the original question: can we do something like this in the conditions?

Comment: I will try, if you can share the input file and expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

You really should post some sample input and expected output to get the best possible answer but it SOUNDS like you're asking for something like:

```
awk -F, '(k=gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "G", $1)) == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $5) &&
         k == gensub(/[^0-9]/, "","G", $6)'
```

which of course would not be a good approach compared to the more obvious and concise:

```
awk -F, '
function f(s) { return gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "g", s) }
{ k = f($1) }
f($5)==k && f($6)==k
'
```

but that might be a ridiculous approach anyway depending on what your input data looks like.